# Where to find active directory domain services sources?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to install an active directory on my Windows 2012 Server R2. I tried to do it using the Server Manager. I followed the [following steps](https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkaddactivedirectorydomainservicesrole.htm): but when I click on Install, I get the following error :

```
"Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed. 
The source files could not be found. Try installing the role, role 
services, or features again in a new Add Roles and Features Wizard session, 
and on the confirmation page of the wizard, click "Specify an alternate 
source path" to specify a valid location of the source files that are 
required for the installation. The location must be accessible by the 
computer account of the destination server."
```

I downloaded the Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (ADLDS) Management Pack and the Remote Server Administration Tools but I still get the same error so I am wondering which sources I should use. Is there an extra step that I am missing?

Comment: Did you click on `Specify an alternate source path` and point it to the ISO/DVD/Media with the Windows 2012 Server R2 install? For example `D:\Sources\SxS`.

Comment: Yes but I need to find the exact path to the sources... because the D:\ repository only contains "Boot", "Deploy" and "EFI"

Comment: There should be a "Sources" folder and within that directory, there should be another one named "SxS". If you don't see the Sources folder, can you confirm that you're using the 2012R2 iso?

Comment: I just downloaded 2012R2 iso from VLSC and it does have `Sources\SxS` folder, along with `boot`, `efi`, but not the `Deploy` folder.

Comment: I listed the features available using Powershell and Active Directory Domain Services is marked as "removed " . So I guess the architects who built this iso have done some changes on the initial operating system... I am not sure that I will be able to install active directory using this iso.